# Docker container port mapping 80:80 only works on localhost but not from external access?

Tags: docker, web-server, httpd

Logged in my intranet server via SSH on IP 10.10.245.209 (port 22 of course)

Created a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    image: php:8.0-apache
    volumes:
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

And in ./php/src I have `index.php`:

```
<?php
echo 123+123;
```

I use `docker-compose up -d` in the current directory, and the container is successfully started:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
9795a5fdd59f   php:8.0-apache           "docker-php-entrypoi…"   19 minutes ago   Up 19 minutes             0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   php-apache
```

Now if I use `lynx http://localhost` or `lynx http://127.0.0.1`, it's correctly returning:

```
246
```

As the web page. But when I try to access the server http://10.10.245.209 in Chrome, it keeps circling for a few seconds and then nothing (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE).

`lsof -i:80` results:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 24074 root    4u  IPv4 129863      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
docker-pr 24081 root    4u  IPv6 131383      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

According to docs and some searches in Google, everything I did was correct?

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you open port 80 in the firewall?

Comment: I would use a other port as 80 on the container due I had a fault in the mapping of the container, however the question is what `lsof -I :80` is telling

Comment: @Itai How do I know if port 80 is open?

Comment: `lsof -I :80` gives me `lsof: illegal option character: I`

Comment: @djdomi I've updated the output of `lsof -i:80` in the question.

Comment: @djdomi By `a other port as 80 on the container`, do you mean the container port or the host port?

Comment: I would use port 8080 for the host, since port 80 seems to be fixed used in the container